# Readable way for iterating over a JSON and creating rows

Tags: typescript

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
  "color": {
    "brand": {
      "primary": "#fff",
      "secondary": "#000"
    }
  },
  "ui": {
    "messages": {
      "error": "#f00",
      "warning": "#0f0"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to create a readable function to create the following output:

```
[
  0:
    {
      title: "brand",
      colorBlocks: [
        { label: "primary", hex: "#fff" },
        { label: "secondary", hex: "#000" }
      ]
    },
  1:
    {
      title: "ui",
      subSections: [
        1:
          {
            title: "messages",
            colorBlocks: [
              { label: "error", hex: "#f00" },
              { label: "warning", hex: "#0f0" },
            ]
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

My attempt:

```
type DesignToken = { [key: string]: string };
interface DesignTokensColor {
  [key: string]: DesignToken
}

type ColorBlock = { label: string; hex: string };
type ColorRow = { title: string; colorBlocks: ColorBlock[] };
type ColorSubSection = { title: string; subSections: ColorRow[] };
type ColorSection = ColorRow | ColorSubSection;

const colorSections: ColorSection[] = [];
const designTokensColor = color as DesignTokensColor;

for (const [sectionTitle, content] of Object.entries(designTokensColor)) {
  const colorBlocks: ColorBlock[] = [];
  const subSections: ColorRow[] = [];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(content)) {
    const hasSubSection = isObjectLike(value);
    if (!hasSubSection) {
      colorBlocks.push({ label: key, hex: value });
    } else {
      const subSectionColorBlocks: ColorBlock[] = [];
      for (const [childKey, childValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
        subSectionColorBlocks.push({ label: childKey, hex: childValue });
      }
      subSections.push({ title: key, colorBlocks: subSectionColorBlocks });
    }
  }

  if (subSections.length) {
    colorSections.push({ title: sectionTitle, subSections });
  }
  if (colorBlocks.length) {
    colorSections.push({ title: sectionTitle, colorBlocks });
  }
}
```

It's also a bit nast that there are so many conditionals. Especially the two last, where the 'push' is done conditionally. Also It's not able to handle more than three levels.

Any ideas or comments for improvements?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it. A recursive function seems to do the trick.

```
const getColors = (content) => Array.from(Object.entries(content)).map(([name, value]) => {
  const hasChildNode = isObjectLike(value);
  return hasChildNode ? { name, sections: getColors(value) } : { label: name, color: value };
});

const result = Array.from(Object.entries(color)).map(([name, content]) => ({
  name,
  sections: getColors(content)
});

console.log('result: ', result);
```